# Is there a way to group my list of javascript files that are required?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to group the requirements into one line, or an indented code block? I would like to not have a long list of files that I need to require at the top of my index.js. It feels redundant and like there is a better way to do this.

I have code that looks like this:

```js
//import all files that the bot needs to respond to commands
const invite = require('../commands/invite');
const ping = require('../commands/ping');
const ip = require('../commands/ip');
const dm = require('../commands/dm');
const say = require('../commands/say');
const massdm = require('../commands/massdm');
const cat = require('../commands/cat');
const dog = require('../commands/dog');
const privacy = require("../commands/privacy");
const scheduleMessage = require('../commands/scheduleMessage');
const help = require('../commands/help');
const guildModel = require('../models/guild');
const prefix = require('../commands/prefix');
const docCreate = require('../events/docCreate');
const remove = require('../commands/remove');
const piiUpdate = require('../events/piiUpdate');
const reddit = require('../commands/reddit');
const create = require('../commands/create');
const guildMsg = require('../commands/guildMsg');
const restart = require('../commands/restart');
const logToConsole = require('../events/logToConsole');
const serverInvites = require('../commands/serverInvites');
const tictactoe = require('../commands/tictactoe');
```

Comment: If all you want to do is indent your `require`s, then just indent them, simple as that.

Comment: You can use an `index.js` file. In there you export all elements and then you have a one-line import outside the commands folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're maybe looking to create what's called a "barrel file".

Step 1: create one file whose job is to import a million things and re-export them all under a single name. This is the barrel file.

Step 2: import the barrel file wherever you need to use the things inside it.

Your barrel:

```js
// src/commands/index.js
// pro-tip: sort these alphabetically
module.exports = {
    cat: require('./cat'),
    create: require('./create'),
    dm: require('./dm'),
    docCreate: require('./docCreate'),
    dog: require('./dog'),
    guildModel: require('./guild'),
    guildMsg: require('./guildMsg'),
    help: require('./help'),
    invite: require('./invite'),
    ip: require('./ip'),
    logToConsole: require('./logToConsole'),
    massdm: require('./massdm'),
    piiUpdate: require('./piiUpdate'),
    ping: require('./ping'),
    prefix: require('./prefix'),
    privacy: require("./privacy"),
    reddit: require('./reddit'),
    remove: require('./remove'),
    restart: require('./restart'),
    say: require('./say'),
    scheduleMessage: require('./scheduleMessage'),
    serverInvites: require('./serverInvites'),
    tictactoe: require('./tictactoe')
}
```

Then, use it:

```js
// src/some-module.js
const {
    create,
    guildModel,
    ping,
    remove
} = require('../commands')

create()
ping()

// or:

const Commands = require('../commands')

Commands.create()
Commands.ping()
```

Be warned: this might frustrate tree-shaking.